# Using XML Source Generator with Generic Library Serialize Service

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, sourcegenerators

I just learned about [XML Source Generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/xml-serializer-generator); seemingly only documented in that single page.

It says to simply add this to my project.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.XmlSerializer.Generator" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
   <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.XmlSerializer.Generator" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And then add this to the Main method

```cs
    var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
```

Now, here's my serialization service. It's located in a different library than where MyClass is defined. Where would the source generation happen? The Services library doesn't know about where it will be used so it cannot generate for them. Would I need to pass in the pre-generated serializer to the service?

```cs
public class SerializationService : ISerializationService
{
    public string Serialize<T>(T dataToSerialize)
    {
        using var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
        serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, dataToSerialize, ns);
        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }

    public T Deserialize<T>(string xmlText) where T : class, new()
    {
        using var stringReader = new StringReader(xmlText);
        using var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader,
            new XmlReaderSettings() { XmlResolver = null });
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader)!;
    }
}
```

What's the best solution here? Is there an easy way to use XML Source Generator or am I better to stick with the current design?

Current my main issue is that it requires setting attributes on Main method for Assembly Trimming or deserialization fails. Faster startup and less dependencies = better trimming also would be nice benefits.

```
[DynamicDependency(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.All, typeof(SettingsPlaylistItem))]
```